# Как в Vue.js выполнить один actions после выполнения предыдущего?

Tags: vue.js

Имеется следующий код. При инициализации приложения я получаю массив объектов с информацией по прокси. Запуск 1 диспетчера дает мне массив из 100 объектов.

Во 2 действии getCountryList я хочу обработать данный массив из 100 объектов и получить новый массив из которого я буду получать в дальнейшем список стран и сколько всего прокси по странам.

По факту получается, что во время выполнения 2 действия, на обработку я получаю пустую строку. Я так понимаю, что эти процессы как-то идут парралельно, в итоге 1 действие еще не успело вызвать мутацию и свормировать нужное состояние (массив из 100 объектов) и уже вызывается 2-е... в итоге я получаю пустое значение во 2 действии.

Как мне выстроить цепочку вызовов, т.е. 2 действие вызывается, только после того, как завершится 1-е действие?

У меня есть подозрение, что можно все либо одним действием сделать, либо использовать промисы. Подскажите как реализовать такой момент

EDIT: как и подозревал экшены асинхронные, поэтому не работает как надо.

Теперь вопрос, как организовать что-то подобное, но без сетТаймаута, чтобы 2 dispatch запускался после 1-го, иначе setTimeout в любой момент может подвести

```
created() {
this.$store.dispatch("getProxyList"); 
setTimeout(() => this.$store.dispatch("getCountryList"), 1000);
},
```

```js
//Инициализация App.vue

created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getProxyList"); 
    this.$store.dispatch("getCountryList");   
  },
  
//Хранилище

const state = {
  listProxy: "",
  countries: "",
  proxyInfo: {},
  proxyCountry: [],
  proxyCountryCounter: 0
};

const mutations = {
  UPDATE_LIST_PROXY(state, payload) {
    state.listProxy = payload;
  },
  UPDATE_LIST_COUNTRY(state, payload) {
    state.countries = payload;
  },
  UPDATE_PROXY_INFO(state, payload) {
    state.proxyInfo = payload;
  },
  UPDATE_PROXY_COUNTRY(state, payload) {
    state.proxyCountry = payload;
  },
  UPDATE_PROXY_COUNTRY_COUNTER(state, payload) {
    state.proxyCountry = payload;
  },
};

const actions = {
  getProxyList({ commit }) {
    axios
    .get("proxy.json")
      .then(response => {
        commit("UPDATE_LIST_PROXY", response.data); // здесь я формирую state.listProxy
      });
  },
  getCountryList({ commit }) {
      // .get("https://proxyfordevelopers.com/api/proxies/?format=json")
      //TODO: Убрать лишний запрос. Данные можно получать из общего списка прокси
        console.log(state.listProxy) // Вот здесь по идее мне нужен listProxy, чтобы разобрать его на другой массив, а по факту получаю пустое состояние
        let countryObj = {};
        let proxyList = state.listProxy;

        for (let i = 0; i < proxyList.length; i++) {
          let key = proxyList[i].country;
          countryObj[key] = (countryObj[key] === undefined) ? 1 : countryObj[key] + 1;
        }

        let countryArr = [];

        for (var key in countryObj) {
          countryArr.push({
            name: key,
            count: countryObj[key]
          })
        }
        commit("UPDATE_LIST_COUNTRY", countryArr);
  },
  setProxyInfo({ commit }, id) {
    let proxyList = state.listProxy;

    let currentProxyInfo = proxyList.find(item => item.id === id);
    commit("UPDATE_PROXY_INFO", currentProxyInfo);
  },
  setCountryPhoxy({commit}, country) {
    let listCountryProxy = state.listProxy.filter(item => item.country === country)
    commit("UPDATE_PROXY_COUNTRY", listCountryProxy);
  },  
};

const getters = {
  listProxy: state => state.listProxy,
  countries: state => state.countries,
  proxyInfo: state => state.proxyInfo,
  proxyCountry: state => state.proxyCountry,
  proxyCountryCounter: state => state.proxyCountry.length

};

//--------
```

Comment: я вообще не пойму, что мешает сделать все в getProxyList?

Comment: Был такой вариант и это первое что пришло в голову. Хотел сохранить логическое разделение экшенов, подумал что есть вариант при инициализации просто цепочку вызовов сформировать, чтобы хранилище не ломать. Возможно ли вообще такое и правильно ли я мыслю в стороны Промисов?

Comment: меня больше интересует что за commit, откуда он? что он делает. Просто при вызове this.state.listProxy логично что пусто, тк ничего же там не определено

Comment: commit так в документации и в книге смотрел https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/mutations.html. Разместил в коде весь листинг хранилища

Comment: console log на this.listProxy что нибудь показывает?

Comment: this.listProxy => undefined//// state.listProxy => вообще пустота

Comment: тут именно надо одно действие вызвать после другого ну или в 1 действии сразу 2 нужных мутации вызывать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82981/discussion-between-paul-wall-and-shub1nk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch("getProxyList").then(() => {
    this.$store.dispatch("getCountryList");
  });
},

  // нужно вернуть промис(запрос к серверу через axios)
  getProxyList({ commit }) {
    return axios
    .get("proxy.json")
      .then(response => {
        commit("UPDATE_LIST_PROXY", response.data); // здесь я формирую state.listProxy
      });
  },
```

Если не сработает, то добавьте еще

```
commit("UPDATE_LIST_PROXY", response.data);
// вот это
return response.data
```

Comment: Сработало. Вот где собака зарыта была. Получается чтобы then сработал, вернуть надо что-то, а я ничего не возвращал. В документации по Vuex https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/actions.html , кстати, это описано, но я видимо сути не понял. Надо с промисами будет поразбираться как следует.

Comment: [Вот](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) хорошая статья по промисам. Суть в том что вызываемое действие оборачивается в new Promise, если ничего не вернуть, то оно возвращает resolve(undefined). В коде выше я возвращаю результат then, then всегда возвращает промис, то есть чтобы добавить что надо делать после запроса к api и после того как вы сделали commit надо продолжить цепочку then промисов, а для этого ее надо вернуть. Я сам когда это писал немного запутался, не такая это и легкая тема))

Comment: Спасибо. Видел эту статью, но сразу не понял, буду пробовать еще заход делать, в любом случае разобраться необходимо)

Answer (score 1):

Действия в vuex это [промисы](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise), они всегда асинхронные, поэтому мождо дождаться результата используя then.

```js
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch('getProxyList').then(result => {
    // в result записан результат выполнения getProxyList
    this.$store.dispatch('getCountryList')
  });
},
```

Советую также использовать `async/await` вместо then если он у Вас настроен:

```js
async created () {
  const result = await this.$store.dispatch('getProxyList')
  await this.$store.dispatch('getCountryList')
},
```

Comment: async/await - не настроент  then тоже пробовал, только без result - у меня было так () => {...}  только у меня почему-то даже с такой конструкцией при вызове консоль.лога во 2 действии state.proxyList пустой.

Comment: result вообще undefined получается

Comment: getProxyList у вас ничего не возвращает, это я для примера показал как с действий можно возвращать результат. У вас не работает какое-то действие как Вам нужно?

Comment: Получается такая ситуация. При инициализации во 2 действие передается пустое значение , соответственно данных нет при рендеринге и в хранилище тоже пустое состояние. Но если я поменяю что-то в коде, даже коммент просто напишу, запускается горячая перезагрузка модуля и данные уже появляются. Т.е. все работает по сути, но начальном этапе есть проблема

Comment: Суть этих действий: 1-м действием сделать ajax-запрос, получить массив объектов и записать этот массив в состояние listProxy

Comment: 2 действие: взять результат 1-го действия провести с ним манипуляции и записать данные в другое состояние - countries

Comment: я так по коду и понял, проверьте мой новый ответ